# Cassandra Cluster Setup 90 TB

Tags: cassandra, hardware, specifications

What would be the minimal and the highest setup for a 90TB cassandra cluster. Kindly include the spec of processor, switch, hard disks and RAM. The no. of nodes is 5. Datastax's cassandra is gonna be used, so I guess in-memory function requires more amount of RAM.

Comment: Hmmm, what have you tried? What issues did you run into? Have you googled for whatever guidance is already out there?

Comment: Thank you for your responding,Now we are planning to create one new cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Document for determining the configurations for the Datastax cassandra nodes. Found here.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/pdf/cassandra20.pdf